# Ansible Replace InLine Results in Wrong Content Hosts File

Tags: ansible

I'm using the following task to update `/etc/hosts` file on my inventory, but strangely I see a different alias being enetered.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "hostname = {{ inventory_hostname }} has ansible_fqdn = {{ ansible_fqdn }} and ansible_ipv4 = {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} and ansible_hostname = {{ ansible_hostname }}"

- name: Fix /etc/hosts removing the old hostname
  become: true
  throttle: 1
  lineinfile:
    state=present
    dest=/etc/hosts
    line="{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ ansible_hostname }}"
    regexp="^{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
```

The output of the debug statement is:

```yaml
TASK [common : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [n2.open-electrons.com] => {
    "msg": "hostname = n2.my-host.com has ansible_fqdn = n2.my-host.com and ansible_ipv4 = 192.168.0.203 and ansible_hostname = n2"
}
```

But when I SSH into the remote machine, I get to see the following in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1 n2.my-host.com n1
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Any ideas as to what might have gone wrong? I have another machine in the inventory which is configured as n1.my-host.com, but how come the alias is getting messed up?

My inventory file:

```ini
[master]
m1.my-host.com ansible_host=192.168.0.100

[node]
n1.my-host.com ansible_host=192.168.0.102
n2.my-host.com ansible_host=192.168.0.103

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: It's not clear from the information in your question why you're seeing that behavior. It would help if you could include your actual inventory file along with a minimal, runnable playbook that demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should generally prefer using YAML syntax for specifying module parameters, rather than a string containing `name=value` parameters like you're doing in your `lineinfile` task.

Comment: And lastly, one potential source of your problem is that `inventory_hostname` comes from your inventory file, but `ansible_hostname` is gathered from the target host. If there is a mismatch between the inventory hostname and the hostname set on the remote host, you would see the output you've shown in your question (yes, your `debug` output would appear to indicate this isn't the problem; I'm just guessing at this point).

Comment: Added the inventory file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Any ideas as to what might have gone wrong? ... how come the alias is getting messed up?*

Because of the hint within your example code

```yaml
- name: Fix /etc/hosts removing the old hostname
```

it is assumed that your are going to change the hostnames of the Remote Nodes.

Therefore the issue might be caused by the fact that the content of `ansible_hostname` is [a gathered fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) on the Remote Node dynamically during runtime and by the [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) module, whereby the `inventory_hostname` is a [Special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) from the inventroy file on the Control Node.

> ***`inventory_hostname`** The inventory name for the ‘current’ host being iterated over in the play*
> ***`inventory_hostname_short`** The short version of `inventory_hostname`*

So to prevent a mismatch of information from different sources you could use the approach of single source of truth.

```yaml
- name: Fix /etc/hosts removing the old hostname
  become: true
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regexp: "^{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    line: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
    state: present
```

Please notice that on the Remote Node itself can be also different sources for the hostname. Therefore you might need not only to change it on `/etc/hosts` but also in several different parts

```yaml
- name: Set hostname to inventory_hostname
  shell: 
    cmd: "nmcli general hostname {{ inventory_hostname }} && nmcli general hostname"
```

depending on your target system even

```
hostnamectl
```

Comment: Where does inventory_hostname_short come from?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer and linked documentation it is a special variable, coming from the inventory. Generated probably on the Control Node via something like `"{{ inventory_hostname | split('.') | first }}"`.